# Как реализовать простейшую нейронную сеть?

Tags: objective-c

Добрый день, не подскажете как реализовать самую простую нейросеть на Objective-C? может у кого ссылка есть на источник?

Comment: Как реализовать простейшую нейронную сеть я не подскажу, так как очень далёк от этой темы, но вот, что название у вас некорректное - это точно. Xcode - это просто среда разработки (если угодно, текстовый редактор с очень-очень расширенным набором возможностей). Наверное, вы хотите увидеть пример "простейшей нейронной сети" на языке Objective-C, верно? Если так, подредактируйте свой вопрос, а то видите, кто-то уже вас минусанул за неадекватно сформулированный вопрос.

Comment: :) простейшая неройнная сеть строится на матричном преобразовании. гуглите. Это не сложная тема. А уж на чем писать вычисления матричного преобразования это от вас зависит.

Comment: Я бы вообще не парился и взял одно из готовых решений на плюсах или си (наверняка есть, сам хотя и игрался с сетями, но в матлабе). На матричном преобразовании вроде только с линейно передаточной функциейможно задать

Answer (score 2):

Я просто оставлю это здесь.
[MLPNeuralNet](https://github.com/nikolaypavlov/MLPNeuralNet)

Comment: Выглядит как ХедШот в голову вопроса :)

Comment: Так оно и есть :)